# React native get country and city

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I need to get users country and city for my app.

I can get lat and log with this code.

How can I get city and country in react native

```
import GetLocation from 'react-native-get-location';


getUserLocation() {
    GetLocation.getCurrentPosition({
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 15000,
    })
      .then(location => {
        console.log('location');
        console.log(location);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const {code, message} = error;
        console.warn(code, message);
      });
  }
```

it returns

```
accuracy: 20
altitude: x0.47877258310501
bearing: 0
latitude: x0.7637253
longitude: x9.9530597
provider: "fused"
speed: 0
time: xx25230494592
```

Also tryed

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        console.log('position');
        console.log(position);
      },
      error => {
        // See error code charts below.
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000},
    );
```

and it returns almost same. alt  latitude longitude,

```
coords:
accuracy: 20
altitude: x0.52203785539176
altitudeAccuracy: 3
heading: x70
latitude: x0.7637262
longitude: x9.9530588
speed: 0.0013554140459746122
__proto__: Object
mocked: false
provider: "fused"
timestamp: 1625231106853
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try by using the npm package to get the address from the latitude and longitude values. [React Native Geocoding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoding)

For this, you might be required to generate a geocoding API key from the [Google Cloud](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/geocoding-backend.googleapis.com?q=reverse&id=42fea2de-420b-4bd7-bd89-225be3b8b7b0&project=days-persistence-challenge)

Code ex.

```
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';

// Initialize the module (needs to be done only once)
Geocoder.init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // use a valid API key

// Search by geo-location (reverse geo-code)
Geocoder.from(41.89, 12.49)
        .then(json => {
                var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[0];
            console.log(addressComponent);
        })
        .catch(error => console.warn(error));
```

Comment: Thank you ,i saw that too but is this for free to use or what :D

Comment: No, this will require you to enable geocoding from google cloud and also requires adding credit card info. for billing so when your requests go out of the free use limits then you will be charged.

Comment: Okay I get it, theres no free way to get this data right :D